# Feature request: Whole thread view while typing answer on Android app

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, answers, android-app

I really like that I can look up the question while I'm writing my answer when I use the web page. However on the Android app, when I'm replying, all I see is a blank screen :) which makes answering difficult for more complex questions as I can't lookup the specifics. Maybe I haven't found the right option? But I looked for it, and it's not there.

My suggestion is to mimic the answering machinery as it is on the website - place it below the questions and current answers. What do you guys think?

Comment: Fair request. I think one of the possibility is to follow "add comment" method with docked text input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something similar exists today with a bug that will be fixed in 1.0.85.

This feature exists today, not necessarily to view both your draft and the question at the same time, but at least to switch quickly between them.

If you are navigating back (either by *Back* button or the arrow in the top left), your answer is saved and you'll be brought back to the question with a bottom banner that takes you back to your answer.

[image: Screenshot showing the draft banner]

In current builds, a race condition exists between saving the draft and displaying the banner so it may not appear until you refresh the question.  1.0.85 will save the answer draft before returning.